# RadioList seems not to be rendered

Tags: yii2

Following code should search records for date. But whatever I click, else-branch in code will be processed

```
<?=$form->field($model, 'choice_date')->radioList(array(0=>'Before',1=>'After'))->label('Please, choose Datesearching!'); ?>
```

model:

```html
<?php

namespace backend\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

class RadioForm extends Model { // A new Class programmed by Thomas Kipp 

    public $choice_date;


    public function rules() {
        return [
            ['choice_date', 'boolean'],
        ];
    }

}
?>
```

Searching-class:

```html
<?php

namespace backend\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use backend\models\Departments;

class DepartmentsSearch extends Departments {

    public function rules() {
        return [
            [['department_id'], 'integer'],
            [['department_name', 'department_created_date', 'department_status', 'companies_company_id', 'branches_branch_id'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    public function scenarios() {

        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    public function search($params) {
        $query = Departments::find();
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) return $dataProvider;
      
        $model = new RadioForm();
        $model->load($params);
        if ($model->choice_date == true)
            $query->andFilterWhere(['<', 'department_created_date', $this->department_created_date]);
        else
            $query->andFilterWhere(['>', 'department_created_date', $this->department_created_date]);
        $query->joinWith('companiesCompany');
        $query->joinWith('branchesBranch');

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'department_name', $this->department_name])
                ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'companies.company_name', $this->companies_company_id])
                ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'branches.branch_name', $this->branches_branch_id])
                ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'department_status', $this->department_status]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }

}
```

P.S.: i just am able to influence date-filtering changing property true/false, for instance like this:

```
    public $choice_date=true;
```

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Any ideas,how to fix this?

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: You're saying that `if ($model->choice_date == 0)` is always false?

Comment: Exactly. This part never gets TRUE, so date always will be filtered for larger as! I just can influence filtering in model, not by user. So I supose, property won't be rendered

Comment: This is strange because from your code that part should always return `true`, regardless of option selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RadioForm` model an attribute `$choice_date` that has a default value of 0 (initially you wrote `public $choice_date = 0;`). In `search()` method you wrote:

```
$model = new RadioForm();
if ($model->choice_date == 0)
/* ... */
```

Which in theory should *always* return `true` because you haven't assigned any values to it yet. You created a variable `$choice_date` in `RadioForm` model so you also need to add an additional line:

```
$model = new RadioForm();
$model->load($params);

if ($model->choice_date == 0)
/* ... */
```

Assuming that `$params` has an array for `RadioForm` model, this will load selected value to `$choice_data` attribute and will have an impact.

Comment: No effect(see code above) $params will be committed, so how to get an array for RadioForm?

Comment: I can't tell for now because it seems everything is correct. There could be something you haven't provided (like controller, full view file, etc.). I suggest to write an email instead with more code as through comments it will be difficult to solve.

Comment: Gladly. What is ur e-mail-address?